# Could not open virtual machine: The virtual machine appears to be in use

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vmware-workstation, ubuntu-15.10

I am trying to open ubuntu in vmware workstation 12. But there is a error

```
Could not open virtual machine:
C:\Users\MANDEEP-THAKUR\Documents\Virtual Machines\Ubuntu 15.10\Ubuntu    15.10.vmx
The virtual machine appears to be in use.
```

here is the screenshot
[image: image of the error]

when i delete the .lck extension folder from the vmware workstation folder and again starts the vmware workstation then there are again some errors those errors  are showing below.

```
VMware Workstation cannot connect to the virtual machine. 
Make sure you have rights to run the program, access all directories the program uses, 
and access all directories for temporary files.
Failed to connect pipe to virtual machine: All pipe instances are busy.
```

here is the screenshot of this error..
[image]

please suggest me what to do.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

press Ctrl alt del, it opens the start manager... locate VM in service and end all process.. then open your VMware it up will work :)

Answer (score 2):

you not only need to delete the lock file but also the .vmem file, close the VMware workstation wouldn't release the lock on the vmem file, you need to restart your PC first

Answer (score 0):

you simply need to close all the processes of vmware workstation from the taskbar.
when you ended all the processes of vmware workstation from taskmanager then you can easily run the ubuntu again in vmware workstation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to close VMware Workstation, on VM's folder find and delete any .lck or .lock files, open again the VMware Workstation and start the VM.

Answer (score 0):

This might solve your problem

1. open task manager
2. go to background processes
3. stop the vmware-hostd.ext process.
4. restart vmware and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I killed the the background task 'VMWare Workstation VMX' and it works.

from: [VMWare communities](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Player/Failed-to-connect-pipe-to-virtual-machine-All-pipe-instances-are/td-p/2896050#:%7E:text=kill%20the%20background%20task%20%27VMWare%20Workstation%20VMX%27)